# Not getting correct GID from html in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

**Html**

```
  <input data-binding="GID" data-source="Person" data-val="False" data-val-required="The GID field is required." id="GID" name="GID" type="hidden" value="502fd4a3-1a3e-4219-a16e-8c8be295771e" />
```

I am using following Regular expression to extract this GID :

```
input name="GID" type="hidden" value="([^"]+?)"
```

But this seems not working and I am getting Default value always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), I would rather suggest going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/) instead, example configuration:

[image]

If you still want/need to go for [regular expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) consider amending your regex as:

```
input.*name="GID" type="hidden" value="([^"]+?)"
```

[image]

as there are some other HTML tags between `input` and `name="GID"` and you need to use wildcard to match them as well

Comment: You are right, I missed other html tags which are in between and did not know even about using wildcard in this case. It helps.